# Using a Scala enum in a Java switch-case

Tags: java, scala, switch-statement

I have a scala enum:

```
object EnumX extends Enumeration {
  type EnumX = Value
  val A = Value("a")
  val B = Value("b")
}
```

Now I want to use these enum in a java class:

```
fun (String eventType) {
switch (EnumX.withName(eventType)) {
       //Error, Constant value required
       case EnumX.A():
         System.out.println("Event successful");
         break; 
       default: 
         System.out.println("Event unsuccessful"); 
         break;
  }
}
```

How do I use scala enums in java switch case without any error?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not doing this all with Java or all with Scala?

Comment: I have two different package, one is in scala and other one is in java.

Comment: Honestly it might be worth either duplicating the Scala enums as Java enums, or rewriting the switch statement as a Scala `match/case` statement. It will avoid horrible compatibility issues - accessing Java things in Scala is easy enough, but going the other way around is a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: you can't. You can only use a few things in Java `switch`, Scala `Enumeration`s don't compile to any of them.

Unfortunately, best practice for interoperability is simply to write enums in Java even in a Scala project.